# How to calculate distance from cellID?

Tags: android

I want to calculate distance using 2 cellID (i am getting cell id from GsmCellLocation class).

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Step 1   Get the location of the two Cell- ID's using [this tutorial](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40524/1954)
- Step 2  Use [distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/location/Location.html)() to calculate the distance in meters.